# Child class to access child class

Tags: php

I have a single class that calls aload of other classes;

```
require_once('class.database.php');
require_once('class.users.php');

Class Bootstrap {

     public $db;
     public $users;

     public function __construct() { $this->db = new Database(); $this->users = new Users(); }
}

$est = new Bootstrap();
```

And that class works fine, but lets say in my Database class I have;

```
 class Database {
     public function __construct() { }

     public function foo() {
         echo 'hi';
     }
 }
```

And then from the users class, I'd like to reference the function, but I wanna keep the code clean and therefore want to steer away from statics.

I've tried referencing it such as:

```
 * $est->db->foo();
 * $db->foo();
```

But none of them work, could somebody please show me the correct way to call it. Thanks!

Comment: `$est->db->foo()` should work unless you have more complexity to your actual code which is causing some sort of error/Exception.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would of worked aswell, but seems not

Comment: enable error displaying and check. I completely agree with Mr. Mike Brant.

Comment: @MikeBrant He's trying to access the DB from _inside_ the Users class, `$est` doesn't exist there.

Comment: @jszobody The example doesn't indicate that. If you look at the code, `$est` is in instance of `Bootstrap`, which has `Database` object instantiated at `$est->db`, which has a method `foo()` available on it. Thus `$est->db->foo()` should work just fine. The `User` class doesn't even come into play in this question.

Comment: @MikeBrant "And then **from the users class**, I'd like to reference the function" uh yeah it does come into play. That's the whole question.

Comment: @jszobody I stand corrected :)  I guess I was more looking at his code example that the description.

Comment: @MikeBrant Cool. So what do you think of my suggested options below? Anything you'd add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have given yourself *no way* to access the specific db instance inside `Bootstrap` from *within* the `Users` class.

You could:

1. Hand the db instance to Users when you instantiate:

   `$this->users = new Users($this->db);`
2. Hand the Users class a reference to Bootstrap when you instantiate:

   `$this->users = new Users($this);`
3. Have the users class setup its own database connection:

   `class Users { public function __construct() { $this->db = new Database(); } }`
4. Setup statics

Comment: I would highly recommend the dependency injection approach specified in option 1.  If `Users` class relies on a DB connection, the Database class instance should be injected and stored in the Users class. Usage via Bootstrap instance would be `$est->users->db->foo()`.

Comment: @Jarrod Did this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could give your classes a refference to the bootstrap and fetch them that way or make your bootstrap a singleton:

```
require_once('class.database.php');
require_once('class.users.php');

Class Bootstrap {

     public $db;
     public $users;

     public function __construct() { $this->db = new Database($this); $this->users = new Users($this); }
}

$est = new Bootstrap();
```

And in your classes

```
 class User {
     private $bs;
     public function __construct($bs) { $this->bs = $bs}

     public function foo() {
         $this->bs->db->foo();
     }
 }
```

Or Bootrap as a singleton:

```
require_once('class.database.php');
require_once('class.users.php');

Class Bootstrap {
     private static $instance=null;
     public $db;
     public $users;

     private function __construct() { $this->db = new Database($this); $this->users = new Users($this); }

     public static function getInstance(){
          if(!self::$instance){
              self::$instance = new self();
          }
          return self::$instance;
     }
}

$est = Bootstrap::getInstance();
```

And in user:

```
class User {
     public function __construct() { }

     public function foo() {
         $db = Bootstrap::getInstance()->db;
         $db->foo();
     }
 }
```